# How to show all result from one table and check condition

Tags: mysql, database, left-join

Hi i need some help for the mysql query. I wanted to display all data from TABLE A no matter what and at the same time shows whether TABLE B had pass current date or not, even the date has pass i still wanted to show all TABLE A result.

```
TABLE A
AID
NAME
ADDRESS

TABLE B
BID
DETAIL
DATE
AID

SELECT a.*, b.bid
FROM TABLE A
LEFT JOIN TABLE B
ON A.AID = B.AID
WHERE date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) //how to play with this?
```

Please help me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT v.*, b.bid
FROM TABLE A
LEFT JOIN TABLE B
ON A.AID = B.AID AND B.date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Answer (score 0):

A `LEFT JOIN` can also return multiple rows for every row in `A` - nothing in your question says there cannot be multiple rows in `B` that match the criteria. You would have to `GROUP BY` (or use `DISTINCT`) to avoid that. Something like:

```
SELECT a.*, max(b.date) AS last_date
FROM   a
LEFT   JOIN b ON a.aid = b.aid AND b.date >= curdate()
GROUP  BY a.aid
```